# Smarty code doesn't highlight in PhpStorm

Tags: smarty, phpstorm

I need help with PhpStorm highlight. The problem can be seen on [this screenshot](http://share.pho.to/9ijrU):
[image]

Part of smarty shows OK but has no syntax highlighting. In `File Types` Smarty has `*.html` pattern.

I've checked it on different projects, invalidate caches and still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: 1) screenshot of the whole editor window where filename is visible 2) PhpStorm version used 3) Screenshot of `File Types` where `Smarty` is shown.

Comment: http://share.pho.to/9il0K phpstorm 9.0.2

Comment: Odd. Can you please 1) Check if it does any better using Default color scheme 2) Does whole file behave like that or only part of it?  3) What about other files -- do they have the same issue? 4) Can you please one of the files that have issues here (share as a file so it can be downloaded) 5) I see you have TextMate bundles plugin there -- anything interesting there (maybe it overrides it). Try disabling that plugin